# Is there a language for defining restful web services?

Tags: rest, web-services, xml, standards, resources

I'm implementing a restful service automation tool for client applications. Basically, the tool takes a config file that defines restful resources, and creates some DTOs and resource classes for client to use. But I need a standard for this config file. WSDL seems well known, but it was intended to use with soap, and for me it seems clunky. I, on the other hand, could invent my own standard, but it reminds me of this situation:

[image: standards]

So, maybe there is an existing nice standard that covers my use-case? Or should I implement my own?

Comment: I would look at http://swagger.io/ which uses a yaml file to define its interface. The yaml can be seen in http://editor.swagger.io/#/ and in combination with the rest of the ecosystem, you get an interface that looks like http://petstore.swagger.io (and yes, tools out there for doing API to DTO).